# October CMS - Make different tab the default tab when editing a page?

Tags: php, octobercms

Is there any way to do this?

For instance, when editing a page the default tab is 'Settings'.

I have some new tabs assigned to the page, and I'd like to have one of these tabs the open tab by default. This is simply so the user doesn't see the code in the Settings tab and cannot interfere with it.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to handle it with a javascript or jQuery code.

Make a new field in your model and its type should be `partial` and locate the file anywhere within your plugin.

For example:
`$/mynamespace/plugin/partials/my_js.htm`

And in your partial write a javascript or jQuery code which removes `class='active'` from the default tab `li` and move it the one you want to be the default.

Comment: This was my thought, but I assumed there would be a better way. But many thanks for your response!

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I'm trying:
`$('.nav-tabs li:eq(0)').removeClass('active')`

and then
`$('.nav-tabs li:eq(4)').addClass('active')`

The `active` style is correctly applied to the other tab, but its content it's not displayed.

I also tried to decipher the `JavaScript API` section of the `TAB UI` document here https://octobercms.com/docs/ui/tab but I couldn't find a way to make it work.
Any ideas?

Comment: `$('a[href="#primarytab-5"]').tab('show')` did the trick. Where `#primarytab-5` is the `href` value of the anchor element inside the tab. Not an elegant solution at all, but that's what I have at the moment. :-(